# onClick event - only one event at time

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have simple javascript function to add borders for each elements inside container. How can I make that only one element can be in onclick state? So just one element at moment should have border.

```js
var fileA = document.querySelectorAll('file_a');

for ( var i = 0; i < fileA.length; i++ ) (function(i){ 
  fileA[i].onclick = function() {
    fileA[i].style.border = '1px solid teal';
  };
})(i);
```

```css
container_a {
  background: rgb(220,220,220);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  

}
file_a {
  background: rgb(245,245,245);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.98);
  transition-duration: 250ms;
}
file_a:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
file_a.redclass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<container_a>
  <file_a>1</file_a>
  <file_a>2</file_a>
  <file_a>3</file_a>
  <file_a>4</file_a>
</container_a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove all borders before you add your new one. See this fiddle for an example. https://jsfiddle.net/e79puv91/

```
var fileA = document.querySelectorAll('file_a');

for ( var i = 0; i < fileA.length; i++ ) (function(i){ 
  fileA[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var x = 0; x < fileA.length; ++x) {
      fileA[x].style.border = '';
    }
    fileA[i].style.border = '1px solid teal';
  };
})(i);
```